# How to read data using Ajax from a php MYSLI function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a drop down menu that will be filled with details from another dropdown option. I'm having a problem to read and pass the data from the first drop down option to the second dropdown by getting the details of selected option in the first drop down menu and passing it to a MYSQLI function which is located in a db class, use that details to run a query and return the result back to ajax which will then use that result to populate the next dropdwon

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">State</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <select name="state" class="form-control select2" style="width:100%;" data-validate="required" id="State" 
          data-message-required="State Required" onchange="return get_state_cities(this.value)">
          <option value="">Select</option>

          <?php 
            $notarray = DataDB::getInstance()->select_from('state');
            foreach($notarray as $row):
          ?>

          <option value="<?php echo $row['state'];?>"> <?php echo $row['state'];?> </option>

          <?php
            endforeach;
          ?>

        </select>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">City</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <select name="city" class="form-control" id="city_selector_holder">
            <option value="">Select State First</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

AJAX Function

```
function get_state_cities(state) {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'db.php/get_state_city/' + state,
        success: function(response)
        {
            jQuery('#city_selector_holder').html(response);
        }
    });

}
```

db.php function

```
function get_state_city($state)
{
    $cities = $this->query("SELECT * FROM city where state ='".$state."'");
    foreach ($cities as $row) {
        echo '<option value="' . $row['city'] . '">' . $row['city'] . '</option>';
    }
}
```

Comment: This has been asked and answered here many, many times. Please do some research first.

Comment: it has been answered by creating an extra php page to perform the query not by performing the query from a function in a class, if u have an answer for it please direct me there @PatrickQ

Comment: Unless you have routing set up that knows how to translate a path like `db.php/get_state_city/NY`, then you're going to have to explicitly call the function.  The principles of how to accomplish what you're asking are the same as the many other questions/answers that already exist.

Comment: am new to ajax@PatrickQ